# What is the computational complexity of constructing and performing a regression tree?

Tags: machine-learning, time-complexity

What is the computational complexity of constructing and performing a regression tree? Is there any analysis or conclusion on it?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a good question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [xgboost](http://learningsys.org/papers/LearningSys_2015_paper_32.pdf) paper.

> The most time consuming part of the tree learning algorithm is getting
>   the data in sorted order. This makes the time complexity of learning
>   each tree O(n log n).

Comment: But note the next sentences: using blocks "*reduces the time complexity
of the tree construction to O(n)*".

Answer (score 1):

The answer largely depends on the procedure for selecting the best attribute to split and the split point. The two parameters that play a key role in the analysis:

- number of attributes;
- number of training examples.

The expensive part will be computing the best split point for continuous attribute (this is essentially discretization), and selection the best attributes from among the set of candidate attributes to split on.

In my experience the complexity is often quadratic in the number of attributes *(denoted a) and linear in the number of examples (denoted n), that is, O(n * a^2).

But, as I said, it really depends on your specific case. Provide us with more details if you want a more concrete answer.