# Why is xgboost so slow when you have a large number of classes?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a sparse dataset of dimensions `(40000, 21)`.  I am trying to build a classification model for it using `xgboost`. Unfortunately it is so slow it never terminates for me. However, on the same data set scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifer takes about 1 second.  This is the code I am using:

```python
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
[...]
t0 = time()
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(trainX, trainY)
print("RF score", rf.score(testX, testY))
print("Time to fit and score random forest", time()-t0)

t0 = time()
clf = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(trainX, trainY, verbose=True)
print(clf.score(testX, testY))
print("Time taken to fit and score xgboost", time()-t0)
```

To show the type of trainX:

```python
print(repr(trainX))    
<40000x21 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 360000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Notice I am using all the default parameters except for n_jobs.

> What am I doing wrong?

---

```python
In [3]: print(xgboost.__version__)
0.6
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.19.1
```

I tried the following so far from advice in the comments:

- I set `n_enumerators = 5`. Now at least it finishes in 62 seconds.  This is still about 60 times slower than RandomForestClassifier.
- With `n_enumerators = 5` I removed `n_jobs=-1` and set `n_jobs=1`. It then finished in about 107 seconds (about 100 times slower than RandomForestClassifier). If I increase `n_jobs` to 4 this speeds up to 27 seconds.  Still about 27 times slower than RandomForestClassifier.
- If I leave the default number of estimators it still never finishes for me.

---

Here is full code to reproduce the problem using fake data. I set n_estimators=50 for both classifier which slows the RandomForestClassifier down to about 16 seconds. Xgboost on the other hand still never terminates for me.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from time import time

(trainX, trainY) = make_classification(n_informative=10, n_redundant=0, n_samples=50000, n_classes=120)

print("Shape of trainX and trainY", trainX.shape, trainY.shape)
t0 = time()
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(trainX, trainY)
print("Time elapsed by RandomForestClassifier is: ", time()-t0)
t0 = time()
xgbrf = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=-1,verbose=True)
xgbrf.fit(trainX, trainY)
print("Time elapsed by XGBClassifier is: ", time()-t0)
```

Comment: So what does it output with verbose?

Comment: @sascha You get no output at all from clf.fit.  It just uses all the cores and never ends.

Comment: See what happens with n_estimators=5 for example. Or subsample your data. These are simple steps i would try first. To see if it's just algorithmic complexity or something is broken.

Comment: Oh, i was under the expression you are using sklearn's gradientboosting. But according to [this](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), this param should exist. Are you using this wrapper? Without any experience with xgboost; i think there are open issues in regards to numpy/scipy-sparse -> xgboost's inner sparse-data format conversions. Maybe not relevant. But it's not as perfect as one would suspect.

Comment: With n_estimators=5 I get `Time to fit and score random forest 1.74196195602417
Time taken to fit and score xgboost 12.865177154541016`.   http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html has "clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], eval_metric=’logloss’, verbose=True)" . I *think* I am using the sklearn wrapper if that makes a difference.

Comment: I am happy to convert the data to xgboost's favored format by some other method if that might speed things up. I am in fact already convert it from a sparse pandas dataframe.

Comment: Not sure if that's the dominating cost (it's one-time). So it looks it's working, but algorithmic complexity is just worse. Not sure if there is anything to do if it scales that bad. Maybe [this is relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42557532/2320035) although it indicates, your n_est=100 should approximately take 20x the time only.

Comment: @sascha It can't be the dominating cost as when you increase the number of estimators fit never finishes.

Comment: Sure. You are right, for this dataset (sparsity-pattern).

Comment: @sascha Is it possible to convert trainX to DMatrix and still use the scikit-learn wrapper?

Comment: I don't know. But i'm pretty sure this conversions is always done internally. Why do it on the outer-layer?

Comment: @sascha Just in case the internal conversion is mucking things up somehow. Something is clearly going wrong.

Comment: I don't consider anything broken yet. Tune the parameters. The algorithms you compare are very different, especially in regards to necessary tuning. Maybe touch the learning-rate.

Comment: What if you set `n_jobs=1`? XGBoost [might not perform well](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6627) if there are other simultaneous processes that use python's `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Which xgboost version do you use? How much RAM do you have available and what is the total size of your dataset?

Comment: as said before, increase `n_jobs` to use more threads. and try reduce `n_estimators` to 50 (default is 100). Then see if it performs better. I also have another question - did you try to debug the process? i mean, maybe you can see on what lines the process spend the time.

Comment: Agree with @σηγ here. Please check the github issue he linked. Its mentioned that if you want to use multi-threading with xgboost, you need to build it from source. The one available from pip isnt built for that

Comment: Please share the versions of xgboost and scikit which you are using. Also, without the actual data we cannot exactly replicate the behaviour

Comment: @VivekKumar The version of xgboost I am using is built from source.  I added the version numbers to the question.  Let me see if I can upload the data somewhere.

Comment: @GalDreiman I reduced the number of estimators to 5 so that it at least finishes. I described that in the question.  I also describe what happens when I increase n_jobs.  I haven't tried the debug process (verbose=True seems to give no extra output). How would I do that?

Comment: So you mean to say that you have enabled the multithread options while building the xgboost.

Comment: @VivekKumar Added full code to the question to reproduce the problem. (Yes I compiled xgboost to be multithreaded)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the running time of xgboost scales quadratically with the number of classes.  See https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2926 .