# Why such different answers for the xgboost scikit-learn interface?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation

I am using xgboost for the first time and trying the two different interfaces. First I get the data:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import dlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
data_url = "http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston"
raw_df = pd.read_csv(data_url, sep="\s+", skiprows=22, header=None)
X = np.hstack([raw_df.values[::2, :], raw_df.values[1::2, :2]])
y = raw_df.values[1::2, 2]
dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
```

Now the scikit-learn interface:

```
xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', seed=20)
print(cross_val_score(xgbr, X, y, cv=5))
```

This outputs:

```
[0.73438184 0.84902986 0.82579692 0.52374618 0.29743001]
```

Now the xgboost native interface:

```
dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
params={'objective':'reg:squarederror'}
cv_results =  xgb.cv(dtrain=dmatrix, params=params, nfold=5, metrics={'rmse'},  seed=20)
print('RMSE: %.2f' % cv_results['test-rmse-mean'].min())
```

This gives `3.50`.

Why are the outputs so different? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you didn't specify the metric in `cross_val_score`, therefore you are not calculating RMSE, but rather the estimator's default metric, which is usually just its loss function. You need to specify it for comparable results:

```
cross_val_score(xgbr, X, y, cv=5, scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error')
```

Second, you need to match `sklearn`'s CV procedure exactly. For that, you can pass `folds` argument to `XGBoost`'s `cv` method:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

cv_results =  xgb.cv(dtrain=dmatrix, params=params, metrics={'rmse'}, folds = KFold(n_splits=5))
```

Finally, you need to ensure that `XGBoost`'s `cv` procedure actually converges. For some reason it only does 10 boosting rounds by default, which is too low to converge on your dataset. This is done via `nrounds` argument (`num_boost_round` if you're on an older version), I found that 100 rounds work just fine on this dataset:

```
cv_results =  xgb.cv(dtrain=dmatrix, params=params, metrics={'rmse'}, folds = KFold(n_splits=5), nrounds = 100)
```

Now you will get matching results.

On a side note, it's interesting how you say it's your first time using `XGBoost`, but you actually have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594499/why-is-xgboost-so-slow-when-you-have-a-large-number-of-classes/48041897) on `XGBoost` dating back to 2017.

Comment: How to apply existing folding array to xgb.cv function? I know in cross_val_sccore there is a parameter groups that can take predefined folding information (so I want to run pre-defined folding, not random folding)

Comment: Use `folds` argument to pass predefined folds structure as a list of lists of indices. `nfold` and `stratified` arguments are ignored when doing so.